# Python Regex to check if string 1 and string 2 are of same pattern

Tags: python, regex, string

I have 3 strings Ex:

s1 = The time right now is 10 o'clock

s2 = The time right now is {data} 0'clock

s3 = The time is {data1} {data2} right now.

How do I conclude that s1 and s2 are of same type and s1 and s3 are of different types. The {data} here is not limited to numbers. It may be string as well. Is there a way to do it using regex or any other simpler solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your `{xxx}` placeholders to `.+?` to convert your templated strings (`s2` and `s3`) into a regex, and then see if they match the string with no placeholders (`s1`).

```
import re

for template in (s2, s3):
    # convert templated string to regex
    template_as_re = re.sub(r'\{[^}]+\}', r'.+?', template)

    # try matching with test string
    if re.match(template_as_re, s1):
        print("{!r} is a match".format(template))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `spacy`. It's more of a NLP problem.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
txt1 = nlp(u"The time right now is 10 o'clock")
txt2 = nlp(u"The time right now is {data} 0'clock")
txt3 = nlp(u"The time is {data1} {data2} right now.")

print(txt1.similarity(txt2))
# print(txt2.similarity(txt3)) 
print(txt1.similarity(txt3))
```

---

```
0.7989319318398767
0.5683103163553128
```

---

More it's closer to 1 more it will be similar. Set some threshold to determine similarity and dissimilarity.

Comment: Hey @Pygirl, thank you for this. However, if the len({data}) becomes larger, the probabilty of the string match becomes less and less and is prone to error. But Thanks anyways. It may become handy in my future work. :)